# C++ Adding binary numbers - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, binary

I´m doing a homework where i have to add two binary numbers. I have some code, it´s really not the best solution, but it works, atleast in visual studio console, but, when i upload the source.cpp into a webapp which can tell if its ok or not, it gives me error:
 **Segmentation fault/Bus error/Memory limit exceeded/Stack limit exceeded**

It started to appear after i added this part of code for deleting "0" before the result:

```
int result_int = stoi(result);
if (result_int == 0) // needed for case when result will be only 0, like "00000"
{
    result = '0';
}
else 
{
    int i = 0;
    while (result[i] == '0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    result.erase(0, result.find_first_not_of('0'));
}
```

Is there anything wrong, that could cause this error?

This is the whole code(unfortunately names are in Czech language)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool IsOneOrZero(string n1, string n2)
{
    bool is_zero;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (n1[i] == '1' || n1[i] == '0')
        {
            is_zero = true;
        }
        else
        {
            is_zero = false;
            return is_zero;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n2.size(); i++)
    {
        if (n2[i] == '1' || n2[i] == '0')
        {
            is_zero = true;
        }
        else
        {
            is_zero = false;
            return is_zero;
        }
    }
    return is_zero;
}
void ZmenaVelikosti(string& n1, string& n2)
{
    if (n2.size() > n1.size())
    {
        while (n1.size() != n2.size())
        {
            n1 = '0' + n1;
        }
    }
    else if (n1.size() > n2.size())
    {
        while (n1.size() != n2.size())
        {
            n2 = '0' + n2;
        }
    }
}
string SecteniCisel(string n1, string n2)
{
    string vysledek;
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = n1.size(); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (n1[i] == '0' && n2[i] == '0' && value == 0)
        {
            vysledek = '0' + vysledek;
            value = 0;
            //soucet prvku je 0
        }
        else if (n1[i] == '0' && n2[i] == '0' && value == 1)
        {
            vysledek = '1' + vysledek;
            value = 0;
            //soucet prvku je 1
        }
        else if (n1[i] == '1' && n2[i] == '0' && value == 0)
        {
            vysledek = '1' + vysledek;
            //soucet prvku je 1
        }
        else if (n1[i] == '0' && n2[i] == '1' && value == 0)
        {
            vysledek = '1' + vysledek;
            //soucet prvku je 1
        }
        else if (n1[i] == '1' && n2[i] == '0' && value == 1)
        {
            vysledek = '0' + vysledek;
            value = 1;
            //soucet prvku je 0
            //value = 1
        }
        else if (n1[i] == '0' && n2[i] == '1' && value == 1)
        {
            vysledek = '0' + vysledek;
            value = 1;
            //soucet prvku je 0
            //value = 1
        }
        else if (n1[i] == '1' && n2[i] == '1' && value == 0)
        {
            vysledek = '0' + vysledek;
            value = 1;
            //soucet prvku je 0
            //value = 1
        }
        else if (n1[i] == '1' && n2[i] == '1' && value == 1)
        {
            vysledek = '1' + vysledek;
            value = 1;
            //soucet prvku je 1
            //value = 1
        }
    }
    if (value == 1)
    {
        vysledek = '1' + vysledek;
    }
    int vysledek_int = stoi(vysledek);
    if (vysledek_int == 0)
    {
        vysledek = "0";
    }
    else 
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (vysledek[i] == '0')
        {
            i++;
        }
        vysledek.erase(0, vysledek.find_first_not_of('0'));
    }
    return vysledek;
}
int main()
{
    string n1;
    string n2;
    cout << "Zadejte dve binarni cisla:" << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cin >> n2;
    ZmenaVelikosti(n1, n2);
    if (IsOneOrZero(n1, n2) == true)
    {
        cout << "Soucet: " << SecteniCisel(n1, n2) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Nespravny vstup." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Always post compilable code.

Comment: In one place (`result = '0';`), `result` appears to be a `char` . In another (`result.erase(...`) you're treating it like a container (e.g. a `string`). Unfortunately you've not included the declaration.

Comment: i have "result" declared as a string

Comment: Post code here.

Comment: I posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop in `SecteniCisel` is buggy:

```
for (int i = n1.size(); i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (n1[i] == '0' && n2[i] == '0' && value == 0)
```

You’re looking at `n1[i]` when `i` is `n1.size()`. You need to start at
`n1.size() - 1`. Accessing it at `n1.size()` is invalid.

Aside from that, all this `if ... else if ... else if` is really
terrible. Use a table or a `switch` or something.

There may be more bugs, didn’t look too hard.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use stoi() method for convert string to integer because integer variable can be max 2147483647. If you put bigger number in string variable, variable will overflow.